# split file by substring from lines on ibm i shell

Tags: shell, split, ibm-midrange

i have a big file with many lines like

```
inv_2007_43324234234.csv
inv_2007_43377774234.csv
inv_2007_43999994234.csv
inv_2011_43324265765.csv
inv_2007_43324298743.csv
inv_2008_97545234234.csv
inv_2011_43888234288.csv
```

...

the second part '*2007*' '*2011*' is the year.
is there a way to split the files in several files by the year?
the rows are not sorted. there should be one file each year with the files that have the year in the line.
i use ibm i shell.

thanks so far
jogi

---

i tried many times to get the command running but now i have an error which i want to describe in an answer.
the base question is answered by anubhava. 
But i have another problem which crashes my command.

i create a list of my files with

```
ls  > myfiles.dat
```

myfiles contains the above descrived csv-files. 
if i try to use this list by the awk command

```
awk -F'_' '{out=$2 ".csv"; print > out}' myfiles.dat
```

i get one csv file which is named .csv.
now i load the myfiles.dat to my pc and open it in notepad++.
i copy a part of it and create a new file myfilefromnotepad.dat.
now i load the new file from my pc to the server and run the command - it works ??

But why cant awk not work with the list created by ls ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If awk is available you can do this:

```
awk -F'_' '{out=$2 ".csv"; print > out}' file
```

Comment: sorry, one question: my testfile works fine. i have CRLF at the end. my real file is very big and created by ls -d $PWD/* has LF at the end. if i try to run the awk command to my real file jaust one file with .csv will be created. the only difference between testfile and realfile ist the count of rows and the line ending.

Comment: Hey anubhava, the problem is, the files look identical. there is no difference between them. i described my problem in my answer. have you an idea ?

Comment: it shows a $ at the end of each line `inv_2007_43324234234.csv$`

Comment: the problem is not only in awk. JamesA answer also doesnt work. if i save the list on my pc - create a new dos file and send it to server al works fine, but why ?

Comment: ok, i understand. i have seen that my ls output is not sorted. i read in many posts that this should be default in the ls command. should this be a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

A shell only solution:

```
while read; do 
test -n "$REPLY" && echo $REPLY >> $(expr "$REPLY" : '\(inv_.*\)_').dat;
done < myfiles.dat
```

---

Verification:

```
while read; do
test -n "$REPLY" && echo $REPLY >> $(expr "$REPLY" : '\(inv_.*\)_').dat;
done <<END
inv_2007_43324234234.csv
inv_2007_43377774234.csv
inv_2007_43999994234.csv
inv_2011_43324265765.csv
inv_2007_43324298743.csv
inv_2008_97545234234.csv
inv_2011_43888234288.csv
END
```

Result:

```
head inv_*.dat
==> inv_2007.dat <==
inv_2007_43324234234.csv
inv_2007_43377774234.csv
inv_2007_43999994234.csv
inv_2007_43324298743.csv

==> inv_2008.dat <==
inv_2008_97545234234.csv

==> inv_2011.dat <==
inv_2011_43324265765.csv
inv_2011_43888234288.csv
```

Comment: that doesnt work for me ? i get all the files in the list as single files ?

Comment: @user1121575 Can you give an example?  Are you running this from a `QSH` prompt?  That sounds like a typo of some sort.

Comment: Hi James, i run the command in qsh. if i copy your example in my notepad on pc and run the script in qsh i get the same result like you. but i use my listfile as input i get one large file named .dat and no several files with [year].dat

Comment: @user1121575 Can you list the steps you use to run the commands? There's probably a translation issue between notepad and running it in qsh.  It would be helpful if you could include the output of: `ls -S myfiles.dat;head myfiles.dat|od -c -tx1`.